# Fresh dotnet new mvc project @ Linux - Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, debian

I just created new project with `dotnet new mvc` but after connecting remotely to that web page (I'm using nginx to achieve reverse proxy)

There's an exception beng raised

> dbug: HttpsConnectionAdapter[1]
>         Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
>   System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
>      at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__51_1(IAsyncResult iar)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)

Anybody has an idea what may be the reason?

Nginx status:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-11-24 23:35:25 CET; 6s ago
Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 16378 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 16383 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 16381 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 16386 (nginx)
Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
Memory: 2.9M
CPU: 47ms
CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
   ├─16386 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
   └─16387 nginx: worker process
```

My nginx -> sites-avaliable -> default.txt

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

---

```
 dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.402
 Commit:    3599f217f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.9-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.4
  Commit:  85255dde3e

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.                                                                                                                                                             All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.                                                                                                                                                             App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

In other file nginx sites file:  `sites-enabled/default` I used this config:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Solution was to change port 5001 to 5000